# Design-by-contract finding pre-conditions

Tags: java, design-by-contract, preconditions

I have to create a Calculator in Java, based on this Interface.

```
public interface CalculatorIF {
    int add(int x, int y);
    int sub(int x, int y);
    int mult(int x, int y);
    //double div(int x, int y);
    //int sqrt(int x);
}
```

But for every Method, I need pre-post conditions. 
I really need help for pre-conditions, because I can't imagine even a single one which makes sense and isn't already handled by Java.

EDIT: division and sqrt are clear to me, but I need some Ideas for add, sub and mult.

Comment: What do you mean handled by java?

Comment: I mean for my add-method I only can Imagine as a pre-condition x or y is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE but this is already handled by java.

Comment: precondition for sqrt is non-negative? or for div is `y!=0`? maybe I'm just mistaken but that might be it

Comment: Division by zero? Square root of negative numbers? Java will throw an ArithmeticException in case of division by zero and return NaN, in which case you should check in the sqrt method whether int x is negative, and it if it, throw an appropriate exception...

Comment: If there's nothing to check, there's nothing to check

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgott to mention that I just need some for add, sub and mult. Division y!=0 and sqrt x >= 0 was quite easy.

@baao yes, but It's written explicit in my task so I was kinda worried Im missing something

Answer (score 1):

If you add two `Integer.MAX_VALUE` values, the result will not fit `int` and will be truncated. On the other hand, if the input domain is restricted, we can always guarantee that the result is not truncated and has an expected value instead.

For example, if `x <= Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2` and `y <= Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2`, then the sum `x + y` will be less than or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so there will be no truncation for positive integers. Similar reasoning can be used for negative values and `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Preconditions for subtraction can be done the same way.

For multiplication, if either operand absolute value is less than `sqrt (Integer.MAX_VALUE)`, their product will be inside the range of `int`.

More sophisticated ways to detect overflow and underflow are possible, but for a class exercise such preconditions seem to be fine.